# how to check iOS 6 privacy setting on contact for a particular app?

Tags: ios, ios6

I have an iOS app reading native phonebook and save them into a local sqlite3 db. you know in iOS6, a new feature named privacy setting is added in system.

so my question comes, how to check privacy setting for my app on reading contact is disabled?
is there any notification sent?

I searched lots of sites but no good result. Currently my app's behavior is,

disable reading contact, when app is switch from background to foreground, or re-launch sometimes(other times works.), contact still showed in my app's list.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Really sorry I didn't notice the rule.

Comment: Please check this link which may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12648244/programmatically-request-access-to-contacts-in-ios-6

Answer (score 1):

now iOS 6 is open to public. I tried and found that is simple. check address book is nil is fine.This is work for iOS release version.

For previous prerelease version, it is not always true. it may return 0 contact number. Anyway, it is not the end user version.